# 07 Camry power steering pump is weak and make noise

Tags: repair, power-steering, camry

I have 2007 camry. The power steering pump is making noise and it become weak. 
My question is the repairing kit does it work in noise case?
I saw the kit come with seals, so I thought it will fix the leak and weakness problem. Does it fix the noise issue too?

Both kits: 
https://www.autopartswarehouse.com/brakes-suspension-and-steering/power-steering-pumps-and-components/power-steering-pump-repair-kit/ac-delco/ac36348379

https://www.autopartswarehouse.com/brakes-suspension-and-steering/power-steering-pumps-and-components/power-steering-pump-repair-kit/edelmann/ede8801

Comment: What sort of noise?  Does it sound like squirting liquid, or grinding metal?

Comment: I guess it is like squirting liquid. However, I don't have an external liquid leak. The fluid reservoir is not leaking. One more thing: I have just noticed that the noise is only when I move the steering wheel. When stand still no noise come out.

Comment: Presumably the fluid is visible in the reservoir?  Have you tried repeatedly moving the steering from full left lock to full right lock.  Sometimes you need to do this to bleed air out of the system.

Comment: Yes the fluid is visible in the reservoir. 
I was having this noise for very long time (6 months) I should move the steering to full left lock or full right lock at least many times (but not from the full left to full right in the same time). Some times I feel the steering wheel is light and some time I feel it heavy and I need to press the pedal to increase the engine r.e.v so the steering wheel is light again.

Comment: Those are just seal kits, they will not fix your issue.